is this only achievable by turning it into an SPA?
I am drafting a website that features a CSS grid with scalable columns. I used JavaScript to build a handle that is used to scale the left column which contains a list of posts that also functions as a navigation. It works really well so far but here comes the issue.
I want there to be a container for the different post-contents one could choose from, but that would naturally cause the whole site to reload with each click into the nav and therefore reset the scale of the colums and the scroll position, but I want them to remain while only the content of the section element changes.
Here is my code:


const resizableNav = document.getElementById('resizable-nav');
const handle = document.getElementById('scale-handle');
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body');

let startX;
let startWidth;

handle.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
  startX = event.clientX;
  startWidth = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(resizableNav).width, 10);
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', resizeNav);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize);
  body.style.userSelect = none;
});

function randomColor() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + (Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16);
  document.body.setProperty('--handle-hover', randomColor())
}

function resizeNav(event) {
  const width = startWidth + event.clientX - startX;
  const leftDistance = resizableNav.getBoundingClientRect().right;

  resizableNav.style.width = width + 'px';
  handle.style.left = leftDistance - 152 + 'px';
}

function stopResize() {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', resizeNav);
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  transition: 10s;
}

main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: grid;
  padding: 3px;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template: "nav head" min-content "nav main" 1fr / min-content 1fr;
}

nav {
  grid-area: nav;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 50vw;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: auto;
}

nav section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

nav section:hover {
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}

nav img {
  width: 100%;
}

#scale-handle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  cursor: col-resize;
  margin-left: 152px;
  z-index: -100;
}

#scale-handle:hover {
  background-color: bisque;
  background-color: var(--handle-hover);
}

header {
  grid-area: head;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 2vw;
  max-height: 200px;
}

section {
  grid-area: main;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="randomColor()">

  <main>
    <header>KLEIN</header>

    <nav id="resizable-nav">
      <section class="navcontainer" onclick()>SHOW 1<br>A<br>R<img src=""></section>
      <section class="navcontainer" onclick()>SHOW 2<br>A<br>R<img src=""></section>
      <section class="navcontainer" onclick()>SHOW 3<br>A<br>R<img src=""></section>
      <section class="navcontainer" onclick()>SHOW 4<br>A<br>R<img src=""></section>
      <section class="navcontainer" onclick()>SHOW 5<br>A<br>R<img src=""></section>
    </nav>

    <div id="scale-handle"></div>

    <section class="content">

    </section>
  </main>

  </div>
</body>

</html>



I did some research and a solution that came up and sounded plausible to me would be to turn the site into a single page application. I would like to avoid doing that since I need to make the site work with Hugo ssg eventually and I'm afraid that this will cause more issues down the road since I'm new to both those technologys.
Would this be the best practice to achieve what I'm aiming to do or is there a more convenient way?

You can save the scaling information in sessionStorage or localStorage. Then when the page reloads, pull the information from storage and update the scaling.
